# Enabling notifications in a Xamarin.Forms android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, android-notifications

Got an app for droid and ios written in Xamarin forms.  I am implementing android badges and notifications using the new Oreo methods, not any of the existing libraries. I can get a badge to appear and a local notification to pop up, but each time i debug a new version they get disabled. I have one channel set up and enabling that in settings makes everything work again.

Do I have to ask the user for permission for notifications or set something in the manifest? I have no idea.

Added code.

```
   public void SendIt(int number, string content)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        intent.SetComponent(new ComponentName(AndroidContext, "App1.Droid.MainActivity"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(AndroidContext, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidContext, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID);

        builder.SetContentTitle("WebcomiX")
        .SetContentText(content)
        .SetNumber(number)
        .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityDefault)
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .SetAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(AndroidContext);

        int notificationId = 1;
        // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, builder.Build());
    }
```

Comment: can you supply code for the notification?

Comment: Code added to question.